# Picture encoding and decoding with python

Tags: python, image-processing, decode, encode, python-imaging-library

First, I got three integer `p1, p2, p3`.

Then for each `pixel`, I got `r, g, b` value and changed it to

`r * (3 ^ p1) % 256, g * (3 ^ p2) % 256, b * (3 ^ p3) % 256`.

That was my encoding and to decode this, for each pixel in encoded picture, I got r, g, b value and changed it to

`r * (3 ^ key1) % 256, g * (3 ^ key2) % 256, b * (3 ^ key3) % 256`

where each key is 64 - corresponding p.

I think this should work since `3 ^ 64` is identical with 1 in mod 256.

Is my idea wrong or is there any problem with my algorithm?

**This is my encoding algorithm :**

```
from PIL import Image

a = Image.open("up.jpg")
rgb_a = a.convert('RGB')
b = Image.new("RGB", a.size)

p1, p2, p3 = map(int, input().split())
x = 3 ** p1
y = 3 ** p2
z = 3 ** p3

for i in range(a.size[0]):
    for j in range(a.size[1]):

        r2, g2, b2 = rgb_a.getpixel((i, j))

        r2 *= (x % 256)
        g2 *= (y % 256)
        b2 *= (z % 256)

        r2 = r2 % 256
        g2 = g2 % 256
        b2 = b2 % 256

        b.putpixel((i, j), (r2, g2, b2))

b.save("changer.jpg")

print("key 1 is", 64-p1)
print("key 2 is", 64-p2)
print("key 3 is", 64-p3)
```

And this is my decoding algorithm :
    from PIL import Image

```
a = Image.open("changer.jpg")
rgb_a = a.convert('RGB')
b = Image.new("RGB", a.size)

key1, key2, key3 = map(int, input().split())
x = 3 ** key1
y = 3 ** key2
z = 3 ** key3

for i in range(a.size[0]):
    for j in range(a.size[1]):

        r2, g2, b2 = rgb_a.getpixel((i, j))

        r2 *= (x % 256)
        g2 *= (y % 256)
        b2 *= (z % 256)

        r2 = r2 % 256
        g2 = g2 % 256
        b2 = b2 % 256

        b.putpixel((i, j), (r2, g2, b2))

b.save("comeback.jpg")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work with a JPEG, because they are lossily encoded. So if you save, say the number 7, in a JPEG, you may get back a 3 or a 9 when you read it back in. You need to at least use a lossless format such as PNG. There may be other problems with your code, but this one hits me first!

Comment: It's really late reply but thanks for your help!